# JUnit View in Eclipse on OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I recently purchased a mac and am trying to get junit tests working on Eclipse. I am using the latest Galileo, but for some reason there is no option to "run as junit" on the tests. What am I doing wrong? There's no JUnit view panel either. However I went into the "About Eclipse" thing and it said JUnit is installed. I also port installed junit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I accidentally downloaded the wrong distribution, which did not contain junit. Consider getting the Java EE edition - it has junit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the right perspective?  JUnits show up for me.

Edit:

You can try opening the runtime configuration menu (do Run>Run as...) and see if JUnit shows up.  If not, try running a software update and pull JUnit down.

Answer (score 0):

Is your test project configured to use the correct version of junit?  Check the java build path of the project.

Also are you tests specified correctly? Using the @Test annotation for junit 4 etc?  I just hit this problem a few minutes ago.